# DoDragDrop() where data is aquired asynch

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, drag-and-drop

My application is a smart client using a WCF service.
I have a ListView where items are filenames.
Files data are stored server side.

When user drag an item from the list, the data is not client side yet.
Instead of downloading the data up front on the ItemDrag event, I want to download the data from the server only when the item is droped (at MouseUp on Windows Explorer).

Is there a way to implement an AsyncDataObject (IDataObject) and pass it to Control.DoDragDrop()  ?
Or is there any other way that I can acheive this behaviour ?

Thaks

Comment: D+D does not require dragging an object with the actual data.  Create a little helper class that has enough properties to tell what needs to be done.  Drag that.  Then the drop target can use it to start the actual transfer.

Comment: I can create such an helper, say RemoteFileDownloader that is instanciated with the fileID and that have an Execute() method that will actualy download the file. Then I pass the RemoteFileDownloader instance to the DoDragDrop() data parameter.

How should, for example, Windows Explorer know what to do with this object ?

Comment: Oh, no, that's not going to work.  There is a protocol for delayed rendering of D+D data but Winforms doesn't support it.  Not trivial to do yourself either.

Answer (score 2):

Fire an event from the Drop event after the drop is validated that will go ahead and fire off a query that will call back to update the UI with the new data.

This will need a loading indicator directly after the drop to invalidate the current area that the data is being plopped into.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my case.

I'm trying to Drag an item out of my application. Indeed in the DragDrop event I can process the data as I wish, I got the actual data.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Out of your application into a second application or onto an OS? that could be particularly tricky without some clever hacking :)

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing is dragging virtual content into Explorer. [Here's an example in managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845654/how-to-use-filegroupdescriptor-to-drag-file-to-explorer-c). [Here's another](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/10/26/creating-something-from-nothing-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net.aspx). In the first example, you would replace their GetFileContents with a version that downloaded the data.

Comment: Thanks
I'll give it a try and post the result later.