# Drag and Drop non existent multiple file to Explorer

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I would like to drag and drop elements of a listbox to explorer.
I made a copy of one non existent file as it is described in this article and changed a bit the program code: [How to use filegroupdescriptor to drag file to explorer c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845654/how-to-use-filegroupdescriptor-to-drag-file-to-explorer-c-sharp)

```
private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.None)
        return;

    byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCD");
    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
    DragFileInfo filesInfo = new DragFileInfo(@"myFile.txt", array);
    MemoryStream infoStream = GetFileDescriptor(filesInfo);
    MemoryStream contentStream = GetFileContents(filesInfo);
    dataObject.SetData(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW, infoStream);
    dataObject.SetData(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, contentStream);
    dataObject.SetData(CFSTR_PERFORMEDDROPEFFECT, null);
    // drag and drop file with name "myFile.txt" and body "ABCD".
    DoDragDrop(dataObject, DragDropEffects.All);
}
private MemoryStream GetFileContents(DragFileInfo fileInfo)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    if (fileInfo.SourceFileBody.Length == 0) fileInfo.SourceFileBody = new Byte[1];
    stream.Write(fileInfo.SourceFileBody, 0, fileInfo.SourceFileBody.Length);
    return stream;
}

public struct DragFileInfo
{ 
    public string FileName; 
    public byte[] SourceFileBody; 
    public DateTime WriteTime; 
    public Int64 FileSize;

    public DragFileInfo(string fileName, byte[] sourceFileBody)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        SourceFileBody = sourceFileBody;
        WriteTime = DateTime.Now;
        FileSize = sourceFileBody.Length;
    }
}
```

This worked fine, but I need to drag and drop several files at the same time. How can I do this?

Comment: i believe you do the same as u already do just with an array of filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found resolve there:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23139/Transferring-Virtual-Files-to-Windows-Explorer-in

You need to override method of DataObject Class: GetData();
For example:

```
 public override object GetData(string format, bool autoConvert)
    {
        if (String.Compare(format, CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            base.SetData(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, GetFileContents(FileIndex++));
        }
        return base.GetData(format, autoConvert);
    }
```