# How does drag and drop in winzip work?

Tags: windows

With winzip you can drag a file from the zip file to explorer. How does this work? Before explorer can copy the file, winzip must first extract it and it must do that before explorer copies it. Does winzip implement a filesystem driver thing or is there a way to detect when a drop event occurs?

I'd like to implement a similar thing in my app - allow dragging a file from the program to windows but the file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop non existent multiple file to Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502643/drag-and-drop-non-existent-multiple-file-to-explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat of a pain to do.  The shell supports various [clipboard formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); the ones of interest in this scenario are CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS.  The jist of it is that you get an IStream representation of your drag object and hand that off to the shell, which then copies it to the drop location.

Comment: Sample code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/19/8080215.aspx).